# Android Studio / Gradle is unable to properly use a library project stored in a local Sonatyp Nexus repo

Tags: android, gradle, nexus, android-gradle-plugin, sonatype

I'm using Android Studio 0.3.7 (latest) and Gradle 1.8. I'm currently getting the following error when I rebuild a simple test project that has a dependency on an equally simple test library project stored in a Sonotype Nexus local repository.

:UtilsUserApp:compileDefaultFlavorDebug/Users/ymedialabs/AndroidStudioProjects/UtilsUser/UtilsUserApp/src/main/java/com/ymedia/utilsuserapp/MainActivity.java:13: error: package com.ymedia.android.utils does not exist
import com.ymedia.android.utils.UIUtils;
                               ^
/Users/ymedialabs/AndroidStudioProjects/UtilsUser/UtilsUserApp/src/main/java/com/ymedia/utilsuserapp/MainActivity.java:27: error: package com.ymedia.android.utils does not exist
        String hello = com.ymedia.android.utils.UIUtils.getHello();
                                               ^
2 errors
 FAILED

Before reaching this stage, I was getting a different error that indicated that Gradle wasn't finding my dependency. The current message seems to indicate that I'm missing something that puts the library dependency on the project classpath.

Here's build.gradle for the APK project

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url = 'http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        defaultFlavor {
            proguardFile 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.ymedia:utils:1.0.0'
}
```

I'm using Sonatype Nexus in its out of the box configuration with this ~/.m2/settings.xml

```
<settings>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <!--This sends everything else to /public -->
      <id>nexus</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <!--Enable snapshots for the built in central repo to direct -->
      <!--all requests to nexus via the mirror -->
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
     <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <!--make the profile active all the time -->
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

What bit of configuration is missing or in error?

Here is the output of running ./gradlew from the commandline:

macbook-pro:UtilsUser labs$ ./gradlew clean assemble --refresh-dependencies
Relying on packaging to define the extension of the main artifact has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0
:UtilsUserApp:clean
:UtilsUserApp:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:UtilsUserApp:preDefaultFlavorDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:UtilsUserApp:preDefaultFlavorReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:UtilsUserApp:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV71900Library
:UtilsUserApp:prepareDefaultFlavorDebugDependencies
:UtilsUserApp:compileDefaultFlavorDebugAidl
:UtilsUserApp:compileDefaultFlavorDebugRenderscript
:UtilsUserApp:generateDefaultFlavorDebugBuildConfig
:UtilsUserApp:mergeDefaultFlavorDebugAssets
:UtilsUserApp:mergeDefaultFlavorDebugResources
:UtilsUserApp:processDefaultFlavorDebugManifest
:UtilsUserApp:processDefaultFlavorDebugResources
:UtilsUserApp:generateDefaultFlavorDebugSources
:UtilsUserApp:compileDefaultFlavorDebug
/Users/ymedialabs/AndroidStudioProjects/UtilsUser/UtilsUserApp/src/main/java/com/ymedia/utilsuserapp/MainActivity.java:13: error: package com.ymedia.android.utils does not exist
import com.ymedia.android.utils.UIUtils;
                               ^
/Users/ymedialabs/AndroidStudioProjects/UtilsUser/UtilsUserApp/src/main/java/com/ymedia/utilsuserapp/MainActivity.java:27: error: package com.ymedia.android.utils does not exist
        String hello = com.ymedia.android.utils.UIUtils.getHello();
                                               ^
2 errors
:UtilsUserApp:compileDefaultFlavorDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':UtilsUserApp:compileDefaultFlavorDebug'.

The build.gradle for the library project is below.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android-library'

repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'signing'

version = "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
group = "com.ymedia.android"

configurations {
    archives {
        extendsFrom configurations.default
    }
}

signing {
    required { has("release") && gradle.taskGraph.hasTask("uploadArchives") }
    sign configurations.archives
}

uploadArchives {
    configuration = configurations.archives
    repositories.mavenDeployer {
        beforeDeployment { MavenDeployment deployment -> signing.signPom(deployment) }

        repository(url: sonatypeRepo) {
            authentication(userName: sonatypeUsername,
                    password: sonatypePassword)
        }
        snapshotRepository(url: sonatypeSnapshotRepo ) {
            authentication(userName: sonatypeUsername,
                    password: sonatypePassword)
        }
        pom.project {
            name 'YMedia UI Utilities'
            packaging 'aar'
            description 'UI utilities'
            /*
            url 'file://localhost/Users/ymedialabs/AndroidStudioProjects/Utils/utils/build/libs/utils-debug.aar'

            scm {
                url 'scm:git@github.com:VandalSoftware/android-cache-lib.git'
                connection 'scm:git@github.com:VandalSoftware/android-cache-lib.git'
                developerConnection 'scm:git@github.com:VandalSoftware/android-cache-lib.git'
            }
*/
            licenses {
                license {
                    name 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
                    url 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
                    distribution 'repo'
                }
            }

            developers {
                developer {
                    id 'mark.rosenberg'
                    name 'Mark Rosenberg'
                    email 'mark.rosenberg@ymedialabs.com'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFile 'proguard-rules.txt'
        proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt')
    }
}

dependencies {
}
```

I've added the recommended target to show the APK project's classpath. The artifact being loaded has a .asc extension which would explain why the jar is not being seen during the build.

ys-macbook-pro:UtilsUser ymedialabs$ ./gradlew showClasspath
Relying on packaging to define the extension of the main artifact has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0
:UtilsUserApp:showClasspath
/Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/19.0.0/appcompat-v7-19.0.0.aar
/Users/ymedialabs/.gradle/caches/artifacts-26/filestore/com.ymedia/utils/1.0.0/aar.asc/8a55d3ff3a51dff343226e85c8e64b1f912e2ff3/utils-1.0.0.aar.asc
/Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/19.0.0/support-v4-19.0.0.jar

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[image: Sonotype Nexus web UI showing library project]

Comment: The m2 settings file is irrelevant here. The only time Gradle looks at this file is when the build script declares a `mavenLocal()` repo and Gradle therefore needs to find the location of the local Maven repo. First troubleshooting step is to try and run the build from the command line, to rule out an Android Studio issue. Also try with `--refresh-dependencies`.

Comment: @peter I added the commandline output from ./gradlew clean assemble --refresh-dependencies to the description. Hope you have further suggestions.

Comment: The next thing to do is to investigate the deprecation warning. Which packaging type does the referenced library have? Do you see the artifact when you print the compile class path? Is it an artifact type that's supported by the Gradle Android plugin?

Comment: @peter I've added the build.gradle script for the library project. As you can see, it creates an aar. Which gradle task can I use to print the classpath?

Comment: `aar` should be fine. Check if the published POM is correct (e.g. has `<packaging>aar</packaging>`.) You can check the compile class path in the IDE, or declare and run the following task: `task showClasspath << { configurations.compile.each { println it } }`.

Comment: @peter Looks like I'm getting the .asc instead of the .aar . Not sure how to check the POM in Sonotype Nexus web ui. Thanks.

Comment: That's what's causing the problem then. Probably the library isn't published correctly. I'm sure you'll find a way to view the POM.

Comment: You can see the pom by browsing the repo and just downloading it. I think you problem is that your dependency in the gradle build does not specifiy the packaging of the dependency.

Comment: Finally got to the bottom of this. The last thing I was missing was to append @aar to my libary project dependency in the APK project. i.e compile 'com.ymedia:utils:1.0.0@aar'.